# Formtastic::UnknownInputError in ActiveAdmin::Devise::Sessions#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, formtastic

Using Rails 5.0.0.beta1.

Installed Active Admin and Devise. Here is Gemfile contents:

```
# Backend
gem 'activeadmin', '~> 1.0.0.pre2'

# Authentication
# Master branch is added for Rails 5 support
# https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/pull/3714
gem "devise", :github => 'plataformatec/devise', :branch => 'master'
```

Followed instruction installation [here](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/docs/0-installation.md).

```
rails g active_admin:install User
rake db:migrate
rake db:seed
rails server
```

When I'm trying to enter `/admin`, the following error appears:

> Showing `/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@mysite.com/gems/activeadmin-1.0.0.pre2/app/views/active_admin/devise/sessions/new.html.erb`
>   where line #10 raised:
>
> Unable to find input class Input
>
> Extracted source (around line #332):
>   `raise Formtastic::UnknownInputError, "Unable to find input #{$!.message}"`

If we look at `activeadmin-1.0.0.pre2/app/views/active_admin/devise/sessions/new.html.erb` (line #10), nothing special is here:

```
f.input :password, label: t('active_admin.devise.password.title')
```

What's wrong? Maybe Formtastic classes are not autoloaded for some reason? I tried to update Formtastic to the latest version, but error still remains.

I understand that using beta is kind of risky, but I want to try this out.

Comment: This might help not sure. https://github.com/Prelang/feedback/issues/14#issuecomment-63241267

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out. Here are the available options:

**1)** Probably the best option. Just use Rails 4.2.5 and wait for stable release of Rails 5 and according gem updates.

**2)** Create the file `app/active_admin/inputs/input.rb` with the following contents:

```
module ActiveAdmin
  module Inputs
    class Input < ::Formtastic::Inputs::StringInput
    end
  end
end
```

Related info is available [here](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/4178).

It solves accessing login page error, you can now successfully login and view dashboard. However, if you try to enter Users section for example, you get another error:

> NoMethodError: undefined method `flat_map` for 
>   `#<ActionController::Parameters>` from `/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@mysite.com/gems/activeadmin-1.0.0.pre2/lib/active_admin/view_helpers/fields_for.rb:20:in` `fields_for_params`

This is because `ActionController::Parameters` in Rails 5 no longer extends `ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess` which includes `Enumerable` (which contains method [flat_map](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/flat_map)).
But I think this is not the only one error you will struggle with.

**3)** This error, error mentioned in **2)** and some other errors were fixed already on `rails-5-spec` branch in [this pull request](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/pull/4254), so I switched to using it instead in Gemfile:

```
gem 'activeadmin', :github => 'activeadmin/activeadmin', :branch => 'rails-5-rspec'
```

Now the errors are gone.

**Update:** I choose **3rd** option and it solves the problem on development server, but when I deployed application to production, error appeared again. I used the fix mentioned in **2)** and now it's OK on production server too.

Answer (score 0):

css master branch of formtastic in your Gemfile

`gem 'formtastic', git: 'git@github.com:justinfrench/formtastic.git', :branch => 'master'`

and do `bundle update` and restart server `rails s -d`