# Admin user form error when using Devise, ActiveAdmin and PostgreSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, activeadmin, ruby-on-rails-5

My workspace is the cloud9 IDE and I am using rails 5.0.0.1 and my Gemfile looks like this:

```
gem 'devise' 
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'activeadmin/activeadmin' 
gem 'inherited_resources', github: 'activeadmin/inherited_resources'
```

In my app I have a User model and I wanted to be able to edit, delete or create new users as an admin therefore I did:

```
rails g active_admin:resource User
```

I can login in the admin panel without any issues but when I click on the create button for a new user I get this error:

```
Formtastic::UnknownInputError in Admin::Users#new
```

---

I have found some solution for this issue:

[Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34529098/formtasticunknowninputerror-in-activeadmindevisesessionsnew%22here%22)

[GitHub](https://github.com/Prelang/feedback/issues/14#issuecomment-63241267%22Here%22)

---

But I dont have an app/inputs/ folder or app/active_admin/inputs/ directory to create the input.rb file! I can't find the folder nowhere! My directory looks like this: app/admin/

**How can I get around this issue?**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't see the forest for the trees! I just figured out that the "inputs" folder is not a standard folder for activeadmin... I just created it and it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

update gem file 
`gem 'activeadmin', github: 'activeadmin/activeadmin'` 
 to

```
gem 'activeadmin', :github => 'activeadmin/activeadmin', :branch => 'rails-5-rspec'
```

then `bundle install` and restart your rails server by `rails s`.
Now the errors will be gone.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer! I am getting this error now: 
$ bundle install
Fetching git://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin.git
fatal: Needed a single revision
Revision rails-5-rspec does not exist in the repository git://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin.git. Maybe you misspelled it?

Why should it help to specify a branch? Thanks again!